# Convert timestamp to MYSQL_TIME

Tags: mysql, c

I want to insert unix timestamp into MySQL using C library.

According to MySQL [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-date-handling.html), I should use MYSQL_TIME struct, like so:

```
MYSQL_TIME  ts;

ts.year= 2002;
ts.month= 02;
ts.day= 03;

ts.hour= 10;
ts.minute= 45;
ts.second= 20;
```

What is the correct way to convert integer value that holds timestamp into this struct?

Is there any solution other than pure parsing of the number?

This is my goal:

```
std::time_t t = 1534963754;
MYSQL_TIME mysql_time = convert_to_MYSQL_TIME(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be using `localtime()` which takes timer values in seconds and fills the `tm` structure. Use `tm` structure to fill `MYSQL_TIME`  structure.

definition of `tm` structure is

```
struct tm {
   int tm_sec;         /* seconds,  range 0 to 59          */
   int tm_min;         /* minutes, range 0 to 59           */
   int tm_hour;        /* hours, range 0 to 23             */
   int tm_mday;        /* day of the month, range 1 to 31  */
   int tm_mon;         /* month, range 0 to 11             */
   int tm_year;        /* The number of years since 1900   */
   int tm_wday;        /* day of the week, range 0 to 6    */
   int tm_yday;        /* day in the year, range 0 to 365  */
   int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time             */   
};
```

And your `convert_to_MYSQL_TIME` function will look like below.

```
 MYSQL_TIME  convert_to_MYSQL_TIME(time_t t)
    {
       struct tm * timeinfo;
       MYSQL_TIME sqlTime;
      
       timeinfo = localtime (&t);
       sqlTime.year = timeinfo.tm_year+1900; // struct tm stores year as years since 1900
       sqlTime.month = timeinfo.tm_mon+1; // struct tm stores month as months since January (0-11)
       sqlTime.day = timeinfo.tm_mday;
       sqlTime.hour = timeinfo.tm_hour;
       sqlTime.minute = timeinfo.tm_min;
       sqlTime.second = timeinfo.tm_sec;
    
      return sqlTime;
    }
```